# Bluetooth module(HC05) works with Arduino Uno but not with breadboard (Atmega8)

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I am currently working on a project that requires communication between an android phone(galaxy s4) and an Atmega8 microprocessor. To connect these devices wirelessly I'm using an HC05 bluetooth module and to understand the connection I'm using pre-built arduino codes(turn LEDs on and off) and an android app called blueterm. This connection is established and able to transmit data when connected to the Arduino uno, but as soon as this chip is removed and connected to a standalone breadboard the connection fails. The standalone breadboard works fine and has been tested with many other projects and I have attached the breadboard connection below. The HC05 when connected to the breadboard changes the blinking pattern to notify the user it is connected but the serial connection is never made. Any help would be greatly appreciated, if any other information is needed feel free to ask.

http://postimg.org/image/itulapqxj/

Thanks,
Brett

Comment: This might be better served on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/. Best I can offer is to double check your connections. Can you post a datasheet or something of the BT module?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I will move over to stackexchange but here is the datasheet for the HC05. http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/images/4/48/HC-05_datasheet.pdf

Comment: I misspoke, do you have the sheet for the breakout board that the module is on, specifically how the header pinout is laid out. I also just thought of: that you might want to check your breadboard too, see if there aren't any broken connections, and your power rails are also not broken.